# firebase httpsCallable is not called / does not respond

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, async-await

I'm facing a strange issue developing a react-native application connected with firebase as backend.

I try to call a firebase cloud function via httpsCallable.
If i'm in debug mode everything is working fine and the saveImage() functions returns a value.

But if i disable debug randomly (maybe 50% of the time) the function just hangs at `await functions().httpsCallable('directUpload')`

I already tried to get an output showing a alert with the result, because i can not use console.log without debug, but its not working. Same for the error. It seems like its waiting for the await forever

Even on the server side, i can see in the log that the function is not called.

```
saveImage = async item => {
    try {
      let result = await functions().httpsCallable('directUpload')({ //its "frozen here"
        uid: this.state.user.uId,
        mimeType: item.mimeType,
        ext: item.ext,
      });
      helper.showAlert(result) //never gets called
      return {success: true};
    } catch (error) {
      helper.showAlert(error); //never gets called
      return {success: false};
    }
  };
```

Does anyone have any idea where the problem is coming from or what it could be?

Comment: are you getting any error message on the application?

Comment: Nothing, the catch block is neither called as the showAlert after the result. Its like if the await would take forever. And its happening just sometimes in release mode, in debug its working all the time

Comment: any particuality shared by the non successful calls additionally that they were not succesful?